# Responsive navigation toggle

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flexbox

I have been working on my portfolio website and I can't get my responsive navigation working properly.

The normal navigation works fine, but the responsive navigation toggle menu presents issues. When the toggle is clicked and changes from the Menu Icon to the X Icon, it changes position to underneath the bottom left of the drop-down navigation li. I would like for the X Icon to remain fixed to the top right of the screen, where the Menu Icon is located before clicking and the navigation li to be positioned underneath.

I have been trying to solve this issue and cannot seem to find a solution. Any feedback would be appreciated, HTML, CSS & JavaScript below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.container_nav").click(function() {
    $("div.container_nav").toggleClass("change");
    $("ul.nav").toggleClass("toggle-menu");
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  letter-spacing: 1.9px;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 60px 150px 0px 0px;
}

.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav>li>a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 18px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #c3dbc5;
}

.nav .current {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  nav {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  .nav {
    display: none;
  }
  ul {
    padding: 0px;
  }
  .nav>li {
    margin-top: 65px;
    padding: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none !important;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .nav>li>a {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .container_nav {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding: 50px;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  .nav.toggle-menu {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: -30px;
  }
  .bar1,
  .bar2,
  .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  .change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  }
  .change .bar2 {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav">

  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="index.htm" class="current" title="Work">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutme.htm" title="About">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="files/Bserene_Resume.pdf" target="_blank" title="Resume">Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.htm" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>

  </ul>

  <div class="container_nav">

    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>

  </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: @Victor, answers go down there.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the `.container_nav` and `bar` markup before the `ul.nav`. I'd also remove the `float` as it is deprecated and use `flex` instead on `nav` and use `flex-flow: column;`. Then you can set `align-self: flex-end;` on `.container_nav`.

Finally, you can add `display: flex;` on `.nav` also with `justify-content: flex-end;` to get the nav items to the far right when not in mobile.

**Side note:** If you want to remove the overflow on the x-axis remove the padding on `.nav>li` in the media-query. This will also bring the dropdown to its true center.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.container_nav").click(function() {
    $("div.container_nav").toggleClass("change");
    $("ul.nav").toggleClass("toggle-menu");
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  letter-spacing: 1.9px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 60px 150px 0px 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.container_nav {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav>li>a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 18px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #c3dbc5;
}

.nav .current {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  nav {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  .nav {
    display: none;
  }
  ul {
    padding: 0px;
  }
  .nav>li {
    margin-top: 65px;
    padding: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none !important;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .nav>li>a {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .container_nav {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding: 50px;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  .nav.toggle-menu {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: -30px;
  }
  .bar1,
  .bar2,
  .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  .change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  }
  .change .bar2 {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav">
  <div class="container_nav">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="index.htm" class="current" title="Work">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutme.htm" title="About">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="files/Bserene_Resume.pdf" target="_blank" title="Resume">Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.htm" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
<style>
    #nav {
        letter-spacing: 1.9px;
        float: right;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 60px 150px 0px 0px;
    }

    #nav>li {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #nav>li>a {
        color: #000;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 18px;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    #nav>li>a:hover {
        color: #c3dbc5;
    }

    #nav.current {
        font-weight: bolder;
    }


    @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {

        #nav {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        #nav {
            display: none;
        }

        ul {
            padding: 0px;
        }

        #nav>li {
            margin-top: 65px;
            padding: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
            width: 100%;
            list-style: none !important;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #nav>li>a {
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        #container_nav {
            display: block;
            cursor: pointer;
            position: relative;
            padding: 50px;
            margin-top: 0px;
        }

        .toggle-menu {
            display: block !important;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-top: -30px;
        }

        .bar1,
        .bar2,
        .bar3 {
            width: 35px;
            height: 5px;
            background-color: #333;
            margin: 6px 0;
            transition: 0.4s;
        }

        .change .bar1 {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
            transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
        }

        .change .bar2 {
            opacity: 0;
        }

        .change .bar3 {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
            transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
        }
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<nav>

    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="index.htm" class="current" title="Work">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutme.htm" title="About">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="files/Bserene_Resume.pdf" target="_blank" title="Resume">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.htm" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>

    </ul>

    <div id="container_nav">

        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>

    </div>

</nav>
<script>
    let click = document.getElementById("container_nav");
    click.addEventListener("click", () => {
        click.classList.toggle("change");
        let ul = document.getElementById("nav");
        ul.classList.toggle("toggle-menu");
    }, true);

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

This looks fine on my end, sorry I can't elaborate, I'm at uni.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).